# Post username and password in Wordpress with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to integrate an external script with wordpress..
I need t create a way that when a member logins this external script, the user will be logged in Wordpress too.
How do I post the username and password in Wordpress.
Wordpress is installed in a subfolder of this external script, same database and obviouly same domain name..
The username and password used on the extrnal script are the same of the wordpress ones.
I just need a way to login the user with one unique form for both..
Let me know!
I do not have any code so far..I do not know where to start!
Thank you!!

Comment: I don't know, but maybe you could reverse engineer it with Wireshark?

Comment: [This plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/phpbb-single-sign-on/) contains all code you need for that. Use it as an example and adopt to your needs. Can be as easy as setting cookies or next to that to just hook into the worpdress auth. Just saw my PDF is offline otherwise I had shared it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't post username and password if its under same domain. Set the wordpress cookie instead. Some thing like this should get you started:

```
require('wp-blog-header.php');
$user_login = 'username';
$user = get_userdatabylogin($user_login);
$user_id = $user-&gt;ID;
wp_set_current_user($user_id, $user_login);
wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);
do_action('wp_login', $user_login);
```

You might want to read more on this: [WordPress Auto-Login](http://www.lbsharp.com/wordpress/index.php/2007/12/10/wordpress-auto-login/)